# How we can remove code redundancy/ improve code by using generics/ any other way

Tags: java, generics, java-8

An example of my problem is shown below. Both classes `Car` and `Bike` have the same fields (`wheel` and `bodyColor`).

In class `AssembleVehicle`, the method `getDetails` is almost duplicated for `Car` and `Bike`. Is there any way to remove redundancy or improve coding standards?

```
class Vehicle {
    Car car;
    Bike bike;

    //setter & getter
}

class Car {
    String wheel;
    String bodyColor;
    
    //setter & getter
}

class Bike {
    String wheel;
    String bodyColor;
    
    //setter & getter
}

class AssembleVehicle {
    public void init(Vehicle v) {   
        getDetails(v.getCar);
        getDetails(v.getBike);
    }
    
    private void getDetails(Car c) {
        String wheel = c.wheel;
        String bodyColor = c.bodyColor;
    }
    
    private void getDetails(Bike c) {
        String wheel = c.wheel;
        String bodyColor = c.bodyColor;
    }
}
```

Here, how we can remove code redundancy for `getDetails`?. Can we use this method only once?

What I understand about generics is: generics allow you to customize a "generic" method or class to whatever type you're working with. For example, suppose you have a method that adds two numbers together. In order to work with the types themselves, you might have to create multiple versions of this method.

Comment: There are basically many ways to go about this. Don't expect this place to be a replacement for you learning about them. Instead: you should be talking to your peers or tutors here. Starting point: it is "wrong" that the vehicle class has a car and a bike member field. Why should it? Why not make that an abstract class, that has the **common** fields that Car and Bike share? And then Car and Bike extend that base class, and add their specific properties. Seriously, don't expect us to write the 1 millionth explanation how OOP works.

Comment: Having two classes `Car` and `Bike` extending `Vehicle` is the academic setup that might help you get through school. When you start programming real applications, you may consider getting rid of these classes and have just one `Vehicle` class, as you don’t need multiple classes with identical properties. Subclasses may introduce new behavior, but the behavioral differences between cars and bikes materialize on the road, not inside the computer. E.g. to a salesman, these differences are entirely irrelevant and hence, their management software doesn’t need to care about them either.

Comment: @Holger,@GhostCat
Thank you for the suggestions.... But these classes Vehicle, Car, Bike has been imported from different package... so, I don't have any authority to change the behavior... 
I am importing to class AssembleVehicle ...
//Note: This is just an illustration of real scenarios...

Comment: You can’t remove the redundancy from these classes without changing them. You can avoid redundancy in your code by introducing a new abstraction, which has two implementations delegating to either of these classes. This must be seen as a work-around for the flawed design of the already existing classes you can’t change. This work-around only pays off if you have enough common code which could benefit from dealing with both classes through the new abstraction. In your posted example, there is none.

Comment: @Hoger, Thank you...
"You can avoid redundancy in your code by introducing a new abstraction, which has two implementations delegating to either of these classes"
Could you please explain the same in example?

Comment: You need a practical use case first. As said, your question’s example doesn’t contain such a use case.

Comment: But how redundant is it really to have separate Bike wheels and Car wheels in your model? Just because they are both called wheels in the current classes doesn't mean they are always going to be conceptually identical. Don't fall into the trap of trying to generalize everything you come across. Introducing a super class in an attempt to eliminate this type of redundancy is probably misguided. Please see my answer for more context.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about OOP in this way places the wrong emphasis. Even if you fix your initial mishap of having a Vehicle with a car and a bike inside of it, the 'improved' model of the Vehicle superclass with the wheel and bodyColor fields is probably broken (depending on the actual domain you are working  in). For instance bike wheels and car wheels are very different, and a sleigh is a vehicle without any wheels. Things that look similar at first glance are not always good candidates to pull up into a super class.

The problem is that we are tempted to assume that if two examples of a category share some common traits, that these traits are present for all the members of this category (BTW this tendency to generalize might also be the cause of many problems in society).

The power of OOP does not come from extracting super classes like the Vehicle and 're-using' some fields. Direct subclassing is a very drastic measure that should not be applied lightly, because it means all present and future subclasses MUST inherit the complete contract (data and behavior) of the super class. As soon as you want to add a new subclass and are forced to make exceptions you know the model is wrong. And at that point changing it will impact all the existing sub classes. In fact, direct subclassing is nearly always a violation of the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), the second in the set of [SOLID design principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

A much more flexible approach is to extract interfaces to encapsulate certain aspects of a category of classes:

```
interface Wheeled {
    String getWheels();
}

class Car implements Wheeled {

    private String wheels;        

    @Override
    public String getWheels() {
        return wheels;
    }
}

class Bike implements Wheeled {

    private String wheels;        

    @Override
    public String getWheels() {
        return wheels;
    }
}
```

This would allow treating Cars and Bikes the same, if you are only interested in wheels:

```
List<Wheeled> wheeledVehicles = new ArrayList<>();
wheeledVehicles.add(new Car());
wheeledVehicles.add(new Bike());
String firstWheels = wheeledVehicles.get(0).getWheels());
```

If you are interested in body color, or even wheels AND body color, you are free to play with interfaces:

```
interface Wheeled {
    String getWheels();
}

interface Coloured{
    String getBodyColour();
}

interface WheeledAndColoured extends Wheeled, Coloured {}
```

Which allows:

```
List<WheeledAndColoured> wheeledAndColouredVehicles = new ArrayList<>();
wheeledAndColouredVehicles.add(new Car());
wheeledAndColouredVehicles.add(new Bike());

WheeledAndColoured first = wheeledAndColouredVehicles.get(0);
String firstWheels = first.getWheels());
String firstColour = first.getBodyColour());
```

If you really want to, you can extract the wheels field into a super class, but the immediate gain is limited. Private fields are an implementation detail, and pulling them into a super class is certainly not the type of re-use that will make a big difference. At the same time, it would create a very strong dependency between those classes and make future changes harder.

Maybe if you need to implement some 'complex' shared logic related to wheels, it is time to create the Wheels class:

```
class Wheels {

    private String type;
    private int number;
    private BigDecimal price;
    
    public BigDecimal getReplacementCosts() {
        return price.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(number));
    }
}
```

Now the Car class can collaborate with the Wheels class as one of its fields:

```
class Car implements Wheeled {

    private Wheels wheels;        

    @Override
    public String getWheels() {
        return wheels.getType();
    }

    public BigDecimal getMaintenanceCosts() {
        return wheels.getReplacementCosts();
    }
}
```

Notice that, because we didn't tie in Car and Bike with a common super class, we are not forced to change either the Wheeled interface, nor the Bike class. If you want to add the Wheels logic to Bike then you can easily do so, but you are not forced to. You would be, if the wheels fields was in the shared super class Vehicle.

So the motto is: Favor collaboration over extension because it's way more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other commenters that the Vehicle class does not really make sense. I recommend following their advice and having Car and Bike extend the Vehicle class. This is better than using generics, because you can "guarantee" that you cannot use AssembleVehicle with classes that aren't vehicles and don't meet the requirements of having a wheel and a bodyColour.

However, if you still want to use generics, here is how you can use them:

```
class Car {
    String wheel;
    String bodyColor;
    
    //setter & getter
}

class Bike {
    String wheel;
    String bodyColor;
    
    //setter & getter
}

class AssembleVehicle <T> {
    public void init(T vehicle) {   
        getDetails(vehicle);
    }
    
    private void getDetails(T vehicle) {
        String wheel = vehicle.wheel;
        String bodyColor = vehicle.bodyColor;
    }
}
```

This allows you to write the getDetails method only once.

Comment: Thank you! for the reply...
but I think, it will give compilation error at "String wheel = vehicle.wheel;"